# Upload Image Directly From Browser Using AngularJS Amazon S3

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images from my browser to Amazon S3 directly, but getting the error of AWS not being defined:

```
   public/modules/users/controllers/settings.client.controller.js
 16 |      var bucket = new AWS.S3({ 
                            ^ 'AWS' is not defined.
 18 |          credentials: new AWS.Credentials($scope.creds.access_key, $scope.creds.secret_key)
                                ^ 'AWS' is not defined.
```

Below is my code:

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('users').controller('SettingsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'Users', 'Authentication',
function($scope, $http, $location, Users, Authentication) {
    $scope.user = Authentication.user;

        $scope.profpic = '';
        $scope.creds = {
            bucket: 'bucket_name',
            access_key: '',
            secret_key: ''
        };

        $scope.upload = function() {
  // Configure The S3 Object 
  var bucket = new AWS.S3({ 
    region : 'us-east-1',
    credentials: new AWS.Credentials($scope.creds.access_key, $scope.creds.secret_key)
  });

  if($scope.file) {
    var params = { Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket, Key: $scope.file.name, ContentType: $scope.file.type, Body: $scope.file, ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256' };

    bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
        // There Was An Error With Your S3 Config
        alert(err.message);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // Success!
        alert('Upload Done');
    }
})
    .on('httpUploadProgress',function(progress) {
          // Log Progress Information
          console.log(Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100) + '% done');
      });
  }
  else {
    // No File Selected
    alert('No File Selected');
}
};

    // If user is not signed in then redirect back home
    if (!$scope.user) $location.path('/');

    // Check if there are additional accounts 
    $scope.hasConnectedAdditionalSocialAccounts = function(provider) {
        for (var i in $scope.user.additionalProvidersData) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    };

    // Check if provider is already in use with current user
    $scope.isConnectedSocialAccount = function(provider) {
        return $scope.user.provider === provider || ($scope.user.additionalProvidersData && $scope.user.additionalProvidersData[provider]);
    };

    // Remove a user social account
    $scope.removeUserSocialAccount = function(provider) {
        $scope.success = $scope.error = null;

        $http.delete('/users/accounts', {
            params: {
                provider: provider
            }
        }).success(function(response) {
            // If successful show success message and clear form
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.user = Authentication.user = response;
        }).error(function(response) {
            $scope.error = response.message;
        });
    };

    // Update a user profile
    $scope.updateUserProfile = function(isValid) {
        if (isValid) {
            $scope.success = $scope.error = null;
            var user = new Users($scope.user);

            user.$update(function(response) {
                $scope.success = true;
                Authentication.user = response;
            }, function(response) {
                $scope.error = response.data.message;
            });
        } else {
            $scope.submitted = true;
        }
    };

    // Change user password
    $scope.changeUserPassword = function() {
        $scope.success = $scope.error = null;

        $http.post('/users/password', $scope.passwordDetails).success(function(response) {
            // If successful show success message and clear form
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.passwordDetails = null;
        }).error(function(response) {
            $scope.error = response.message;
        });
    };
}
    ])
    .directive('fileread', [function(){
        return {
            scope: {
                fileread: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                element.bind('change', function(changeEvent) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(loadEvent) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                        });
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
                });
            }
         };
    }]);
```

Not sure what th eproblem is, as this is my very first time using Angular & dealing wi/ S3.

Comment: Forget about angular for a sec. Just try out some code for s3 and see if that works. Then add on Angular. Then you'll know if the problem is with Angular or S3.

Comment: If AWS is not defined then it probably means that you forgot to add the script regarding s3. make sure the script tag that defines AWS is above the Angular scripts.

Comment: what would these AWS script tags look like?

Comment: I haven't used AWS before but if you are using AWS.S3, then obviously AWS.S3 must be defined before using it. AWS is not a built in feature in the browser. I'm not sure how the script looks like, but I'll assume you would have to write something like this: <script src="path/to/aws.js"></script> in the head tage. Like I said remove the angular stuff and see if you got the S3 stuff correct first!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you added the AWS script.

From looking at this:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js

I believe you may have forgot this in your HTML file:

```
<head>
    ....
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.17.min.js"></script>
    ....
</head>
```

Or if it is stored locally:

```
<head>
    ....
    <script src="path/to/file/aws-sdk-2.1.17.min.js"></script>
    ....
</head>
```

Or something similar

If you are using aws in the backend & a Node server then you'll need use require it like this (however looking at your code it looks like you are doing it in the frontend):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-intro.html

Comment: Where is that exactly supposed to go?  In my file that I posted above?  or in the HTML file?

Comment: This is meant to go in the head tag before your angular script tags. I'm assuming this is front end scripts right. You not using Node.js for your server right?

Comment: Edited the post. But looking at your post it looks like your using aws on the frontend, so you'll just use the first thing I suggested.

Comment: So this resolved it.  But now I am getting the error saying 'require' is not defined & the picture is still not being uploaded.

Comment: There are a couple of angular modules which wrap the AWS functionality, and provide services and directives to directly upload to your S3 bucket. If you are interested, you can see the 2 packages [here](http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=aws)

Comment: The first thing I need to understand is if the above code is in the front or backend. If it is in the frontend that you shouldn't use the require. Use the script tag as shown in the answer. Could you please paste more of your code in your question so I can see what the problem is better as well. Also like I said before, remove the Angular stuff out and try the s3 stuff on its own and see where exactly the problem is. Does any s3 stuff work?